# What software would I use to make an automation bot that I could use for a web interface?

Tags: web-apps

I was wanting to make a bot to interface with Instagram that I could have add users and send messages, but I can't figure out a way to do it and I was thinking the simplest way would be to just create an automation tool to click for me, but it would need to be able to see who is in the group chat.

I cannot find a solution to this problem and if you know of any other software that would work I would really like help I'm new to programming so I'm having trouble.